# how to check and uncheck the checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox inside the table when i click the table row the check box have to be toggle check and unchecked dynamically -- my code

```
<table class="authoriseTable"> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction Type</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction ID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Entire content inside the table has came dynamically

```
    $(document).on('click', '.authoriseTable tr', function(){
        var checkBoxes = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
        checkBoxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false);
    })
```

It is not working
any one help me on this issue

Comment: `this` returns to the tr, so will never be `:checked` - you want this overload (pass a function as the value) https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function

Comment: What you mean by "_not working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @palaѕн _"What is the expected behaviour?"_ -> "when i click the table row the check box have to be toggle check and unchecked dynamically". Obviously that also answers your first question.

Comment: current behaviour: checkbox is empty
expected : when i am clicking the * tr row* the *check box* will be checked and unchecked behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `this` refers to the `tr` which does not have the `checked` property. That's only on the child checkbox.

Also note that the code can be made more succinct by using the `:checkbox` selector and an arrow function on `prop()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.authoriseTable tr', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'INPUT')
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', (i, c) => !c);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authoriseTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction Type</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction ID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's also worth noting that this can be achieved without the need of JS by using the `label` HTML element:

```html
<table class="authoriseTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
    <td><label for="cb1">Transaction Type</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
    <td><label for="cb2">Transaction ID</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While useful to know about `label for=` I think OP wants to click anywhere on the row but has only provided a limit row for *minimal* example in the question.  Might be that there's only a label+checkbox though.

Comment: You're both correct. @palaѕн I've edited the answer to fix that, thanks

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to share my views to help you create the best possible answer for both current and future viewers experiencing similar problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
checkBoxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false);
```

The `this` refers to the tr, you need the overload that passes a function (for each checkbox in the jquery collection)

```
checkBoxes.prop('checked', function(i, val) { return !val });
```

https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function

Updated fiddle:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.authoriseTable tr', function() {
  var checkBoxes = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkBoxes.prop('checked', function(i, val) { return !val });
})
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authoriseTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction Type</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction ID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Note that your code runs the problem of the checkbox default action interfering with the click action, so clicking on the checkbox itself will toggle it twice.

As this will (almost-)always be the case where you have a checkbox in a `tr` and click the `tr` to toggle and in the interests of completeness, here's an option to solve that issue:

You can add a class to the input's `td` and then filter that on the click event (changing to `td` instead of `tr`), giving

```
<td class='norowclick'><input type="checkbox"></td>
```

and 
    $(document).on('click', '.authoriseTable tr td:not(.norowclick)'

This has the added benefit that you can reuse .norowclick where you don't want to toggle the input (eg clicking to show a related child table).

Caveat: It does have the downside that clicking in the td around the input won't toggle it.  It's an alternative, flexible option.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.authoriseTable tr td:not(.norowclick)', function() {
  var checkBoxes = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkBoxes.prop('checked', function(i, val) { return !val });
})
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authoriseTable">
  <tr>
    <td class='norowclick'><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction Type</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='norowclick'><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction ID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, but what you mean by "_but that's your next question_"?

Comment: @palaѕн I mean, this question is about how to check and uncheck a bunch of checkboxes in one go.  Single question.  It happens to be on a row and toggling a checkbox that's the child of the row you're clicking on will always have this problem, but that's not what this question is about, this question is about how to check and uncheck.  So, because this is a **new problem** (not evident at the time of asking the question) OP should ask a **new question**.

Comment: @palaѕн We often go the extra mile to answer additional questions and in this case I've advised that it will be a problem rather than wait for them to find it on their own, but we **do not** solve all their problems in a single question (or we'd be here forever) - in this case I believe it should be a new question.

Comment: @palaѕн as many things, it's open to interpretation, for example Rory has chosen to include the fix as it's relatively minor.  I believe my answer answers the question as asked.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I totally agree with you on this.

Comment: @palaѕн funny, I agreed with your other comment regarding future viewers - this scenario will likely always be the case (which is why I noted it due to experience) so makes sense to include a solution here rather than then have to search again.  :)   I was thinking at the time that there's probably a duplicate for the click row double-toggles checkbox (so 2nd question would be closed as duplicate).

Comment: Yes, I also feel duplicate of most of the jQuery questions already exists, but it's buried underneath millions of other modified questions and SEO is unable to put them on top in search results :D

Answer (score 0):

Trigger with checkbox

```js
$(' .authoriseTable input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
    var checkBoxes = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    
    if($(checkBoxes).prop("checked") == true)
    {
      $(checkBoxes).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
      $(checkBoxes).prop('checked', true);
    }
})
```

```html
<table class="authoriseTable"> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction Type</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction ID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Trigger with table row

```js
$(' .authoriseTable tr').on('click', function(){
    var checkBoxes = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    
    if($(checkBoxes).prop("checked") == true)
    {
      $(checkBoxes).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
      $(checkBoxes).prop('checked', true);
    }
})
```

```html
<table class="authoriseTable"> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction Type</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Transaction ID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```